# Mockito : argument type mismatch?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am getting FAILED: `processStandaloneCancelAuthRequest(00, "true")`
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:` argument type mismatch....error. I am doing unit testing using Mockito and passing `00` as sample input and true is the sample output.

```
  @BeforeMethod
  public void  beforeMethod(){
      super.beforeMethod();

      authProcessor = new MastercardCancelAuthProcessor();
      authProcessor.setPaymentRqIsoAuthRqTransformer(paymentRqIsoAuthRqTransformer);
      authProcessor.setIsoAuthRsPaymentRsTransformer(isoAuthRsPaymentRsTransformer);
      authProcessor.setAuthDatabaseUpdater(authDatabaseUpdater);
      authProcessor.setSsgIsoService(ssgIsoService);
      authProcessor.setRemarkGeneratorSelector(remarkGeneratorSelector);
      authProcessor.setIsoMessageTransformer(isoMessageTransformer);
      authProcessor.setOutMasker(outMasker);
      authProcessor.setInMasker(inMasker);
      List<Validator<PaymentRQ>> validators = new    ArrayList<Validator<PaymentRQ>>      ();
       validators.add(validator);
       authProcessor.setValidators(validators);

       requestInfo = new RequestInfo();
       requestInfo.setTransactionId(TRANS_ID);
       authProcessor.setRequestInfo(requestInfo);
       // authProcessor.setUpdateAuthDatabase(true);
       paymentRq = new MockPaymentRQFactory().createDefaultPaymentRQ();
       Action action = new Action();
       action.setType(SubAction.VOID.getValue());
       action.setValue(PaymentConstant.CANCEL_AUTH_ACTION);
       paymentRq.setAction(action);

   }


   @DataProvider
   public Object[][] createDataProviderForTestingVariousApprovalCodes(){
       return new Object[][]{
          { "00", "true"},
          {"08", "true"},
        };
   }

   @Test(dataProvider = "createDataProviderForTestingVariousApprovalCodes")
   public void processStandaloneCancelAuthRequest(PaymentRQ paymentRq, String    transactionId) throws PymtApplicationException {

        MastercardCancelIsoMessageRequestHolder req = mock(MastercardCancelIsoMessageRequestHolder.class);
        requestInfo.setRequestObject(paymentRq);
        when(paymentRqIsoAuthRqTransformer.transform()).thenReturn(req);

        SSGDataObject routingInfo = new SSGDataObject();
          when(routingInfoCreator.createRoutingInfo(paymentRq.getAction().getValue(),paymentRq.getMerchantDetail().getMerchantID())).thenReturn(routingInfo);

        MastercardCancelIsoMessageResponseHolder resp = mock(MastercardCancelIsoMessageResponseHolder.class);
        when(ssgIsoService.send(eq(req), eq(isoMessageTransformer), any(PciDataMasker.class), any(PciDataMasker.class), eq(routingInfo))).thenReturn(resp);

        PaymentRS paymentRs = createDummyPaymentRS(paymentRq);
           when(isoAuthRsPaymentRsTransformer.transformIsoAuthRsToPaymentRs(paymentRq, req, resp)).thenReturn(paymentRs);

        when(remarkGeneratorSelector.select(paymentRq)).thenReturn(remarkGenerator);
        String remark1 = "REMARK1";
        List<String> authRemarks = Arrays.asList(remark1);
        when(remarkGenerator.generateRemarks(RemarkType.CANCEL_AUTH, paymentRq, paymentRs)).thenReturn(authRemarks);


        PaymentRS actualPaymentRs = authProcessor.processRequest( paymentRq, TRANS_ID);
        assertEquals(actualPaymentRs, paymentRs);

        verify(validator).validate(paymentRq);
        verify(routingInfoCreator).createRoutingInfo(paymentRq.getAction().getValue(),paymentRq.getMerchantDetail().getMerchantID());
        verify(paymentRqIsoAuthRqTransformer).transform();
        verify(paymentRqIsoAuthRqTransformer).init();
        verify(ssgIsoService).send(eq(req), eq(isoMessageTransformer), eq(outMasker), eq(inMasker), eq(routingInfo));
        verify(isoAuthRsPaymentRsTransformer).transformIsoAuthRsToPaymentRs(paymentRq, req, resp);
       // verify(authDatabaseUpdater).updateAuthRecords(TRANS_ID, paymentRq, req, resp,paymentRs);
        verify(remarkGeneratorSelector).select(paymentRq);
        verify(remarkGenerator).generateRemarks(RemarkType.CANCEL_AUTH,paymentRq, paymentRs);
    }

    private PaymentRS createDummyPaymentRS(PaymentRQ paymentRq2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is due to Mockito.

This test method:

```
public void processStandaloneCancelAuthRequest(PaymentRQ paymentRq, String    transactionId)
```

requires a `PaymentRQ` object and a `String`. However, you return 2 `String`s in your `DataProvider`:

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] createDataProviderForTestingVariousApprovalCodes(){
   return new Object[][]{
      { "00", "true"},
      {"08", "true"},
    };
}
```

You should return `PaymentRQ` objects in the `DataProvider`.

So suppose `PaymentRQ` takes a String as parameter in its constructor, you could do something like this:

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] createDataProviderForTestingVariousApprovalCodes(){
   return new Object[][]{
      { new PaymentRQ("00"), "true"},
      { new PaymentRQ("08"), "true"},
    };
}
```

Comment: how should a return type of PaymentRQ be invoked as constant in DataProvider ?

Comment: There is no class file of PaymentRQ, so it shows the constructor PaymentRQ(String) is undefined...although i can put no arguments in PaymentRQ but that is what not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The dataprovider does not have correct values. It is expecting a PaymentRQ object and a string object.
Create a mock if required for the PaymentRQ object and use that in the dataprovider.

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] createDataProviderForTestingVariousApprovalCodes(){
   return new Object[][]{
      { <mock object here>, "true"},
      { <mock object here>, "true"},
    };
}
```

Also when creating the mock object set the return for any methods that can be called on the mock object.

```
when(mock.methodName).thenReturn("00");
```

etc.

Comment: Ok. I have mocked it. But how should i call it in dataprovider ? The input should be in constant. How do i put a constant in there ? and the desired output should be "true" which is string.